# I am trying to install Oracle SOA suite. However I while installing I am getting an error

Tags: oracle11g, wsdl, jdeveloper, bpel, soa-suite

I am trying to install Oracle SOA suite. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/soasuite/downloads/index.html

So, now when I go to my location where I have my JDK and run the following command
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/soasuite/downloads/index.html
I get the following error:
[image]

It says 
could not create java virtual machine
and then gives the following error

"Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for object heap"

I am new to this software. Please help

Answer (score 2):

Seems that your JDK is under a path that includes a space (Program Files).
Move the JDK to be in a path that doesn't have spaces and try again.

Comment: Thanks Shay. I however figured out it was taking in JDK for 32 bit rather than then 64 bits. So changing that solved the problem.